# json.net error (windows 10)

Tags: c#, json, json.net, windows-10

i have a app in windows 8.1 universal app working fine.
in upgrade to windows 10, i have a error:

> Assenbly 'Newtonsoft.json' invokes
>   'Attribute.GetCustomAtributtes(Assembly)' which is not in the windows
>   store profile.

and

> Assenbly 'Newtonsoft.json' invokes
>   'Attribute.GetCustomAtributtes(MemberInfo, bool)' which is not in the windows
>   store profile.

and

> Assenbly 'Newtonsoft.json' invokes
>   'Attribute.GetCustomAtributtes(ParameterInfo, bool)' which is not in the windows
>   store profile.

json.net is not compatible with windows 10?

Comment: I guess you're using VS2015RC. Could you also say which version of the Json.Net NuGet package you're using? And what exact action within VS is leading to those error messages? (I know RoguePlanetoid provided an answer, but I don't believe his workaround is necessary, and I'd like to get to the bottom of this).

Answer (score 2):

Yes JSON.NET works with Windows 10, I had to use the Source Code from GitHub and add that code to a Windows 10 Class Library with a few warnings it compiles fine, and warnings are regards to some Method decorators, the Nuget package did produce some errors similar to this but got it to work fine.

Comment: Awesome glad that's worked for you too, hopefully Nuget version will be updated to work with Windows 10